# how to create grid view with 3 columns in MFC using CMFCPropertyGridCtrl class?

Tags: gridview, mfc

I am new to mfc and I need to have a control with 3 columns with 3rd column being editable. I want to know that whether CMFCPropertyGridCtrl class can be used for this case? if so, can someone provide me a basic flow/code snippet for it?

Comment: Try editable ListView control, [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29064/CGridListCtrlEx-Grid-Control-Based-on-CListCtrl)

Answer (score 2):

The `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` by design supports only two columns **Name** and **Value**. You should use `CListCtrl` to achieve what you need. Placing an edit control in `CListCtrl` is easier by setting the `LVS_EDITLABELS` style. Use `EditLabel()` function to place an edit control for a specific item, and retrieve the new text from edit control using `GetEditControl()` function by handling `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` notification.

You can also use open source implementations of Grid Ctrl like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27

Also there are several commercial MFC extension libraries like **BCGControlBar** and **CodeJock** that do have/implement such controls.